# win32console installed, doesn't 'require' as expected

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Win32Console *did* install:

```
Fetching: win32console-1.3.0-x86-mingw32.gem (100%)
Successfully installed win32console-1.3.0-x86-mingw32
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for win32console-1.3.0-x86-mingw32...
Installing RDoc documentation for win32console-1.3.0-x86-mingw32...
```

but it doesn't want to work with `require`. I see this everywhere:

```
require 'Win32/Console/ANSI'
```

But everytime I try it a `LoadError` is raised.

Is there something I'm missing here? Do I need to configure it somehow?

P.S.:

The error message:

```
LoadError: no such file to load -- Win32/Console/ANSI
        from path/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from path/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from (irb):23
        from path/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

---

`gem list win32console` gives:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

win32console (1.3.0 x86-mingw32)
```

---

`gem environment` gives:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.7.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2011-07-09 patchlevel 290) [i386-mingw32]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: rubypath/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: rubypath/bin/ruby.exe
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: rubypath/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-mingw32
  - GEM PATHS:
     - rubypath/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
     - userpath/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

(paths truncated because they are long)

---

Finally: `ruby -v`:

```
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09) [i386-mingw32]
```

Comment: Try posting the full error plus the output of the following commands: gem list win32console, gem environment, ruby -v

Comment: That 'rubypath' looks suspicious to me. I recommend reinstalling with the 1.9.3 installer from rubyinstaller.org

Comment: @pguardiario Does the path after that look bad? I'm on windows and the path to ruby is very long so I just chopped the unnecessary part off. Is there anything else wrong with it?

Comment: Why is the path so long? How about putting it in c:\ruby193 (no spaces in the path would be good)

Comment: Hmm... I could have. Guess I'm an organized freak :-)  I will try to upgrade Ruby though (running 1.9.2 now), and will see if that helps. There are no spaces in the path, though.

Comment: Any luck with this one? I have the same exact issue, same exact environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to example from here: https://github.com/luislavena/win32console you should:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'win32console'
include Win32::Console::ANSI
include Term::ANSIColor
```

In the same README you can read that

> Win32::Console has been deprecated in favor of an external tool named ANSICON:

1. http://blog.mmediasys.com/2010/11/24/we-all-love-colors/
2. https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon

ANSICON is universal tool and you use it in ruby with gem: https://github.com/flori/term-ansicolor

Comment: Well, it fails while `require`ing `win32console`. +1 for the information on ANSICON, though :)

Comment: And did you `require 'rubygems'`?

Comment: Yes I did. That didn't change anything

Comment: Try running `irb` and then manually `require` `rubygems` and `win32console`. Maybe there's problem somewhere else...

Comment: Tried that countless times, but it didn't work any one of them. Never mind this whole thing, though, I completely switched to ANSICON :)

Comment: I find  `include Term::ANSIColor` gives an error.   Also I find the other lines you give `require 'rubygems'` and `require 'win32console'`  and `include Win32::Console::ANSI` are superfluous/unnecessary. And you don't mention this but I find you have to have gem 'win32console' in the gemfile as well as having done gem install win32console.  i.e. EE33's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Hey I was having this same issue.  I am also the one that put the bounty up.  I finally got passed this error. this is what i did.

As you correctly did, I installed the gem.

```
gem install win32console
```

then I went into my gemfile and also added this gem to the bottom.

Seems to work! How do I get my bounty back!!

Comment: You can't get the bounty back - your best option will be to grant it to  yourself - you won't get any reputation back though.

Comment: oh, I see. I can't. that sucks

Comment: Sorry, thought it was possible - probably removed at some point.

Comment: Ok @ShadowWizard here's the plan:  You write an answer, and I give you the bounty. Then you offer a bounty on a question I wrote or something and give it to me. OK? Break!

Comment: Sorry man that's not how the system works and I won't risk tricking the system - 50 rep are not that bad, meager 5 upvotes and you get it back. :)

Comment: This works for me 100%.  (when I was following hartl's chapter 3 and rails test was telling me to install win32console when I thought I had). Whereas Yax's answer which you accepted, didn't.   All I needed to add was `gem 'win32console'` to the gemfile.

Answer (score 0):

See this thread: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/133808

> Hi everybody,
>
> I figured out, what the problem was:
>
> Just renamed the path in the gems dir:
>
> win32console-1.0.8-x86-mswin32
>   to
>   win32console-1.0.8-i386-mswin32
>
> then it works for me.

Comment: Doesn't help much because instead of `mswin32` it says `mingw32` (Probably because I'm using Windows 7). I tried replacing x86 with i386, but that didn't change anything.